# jQuery SlideReveal Won't Show onLoad

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wonder if someone can please help, I am using the jquery.slidereveal.js from 'https://nnattawat.github.io/slideReveal/' the code plugin itself works fine if I click the trigger manually to open and close the menu.

I would however like it to default on page load, to whatever state the user has previously clicked.

For example if they click to show and then navigate to another screen, when the JS loads again I want it to check the last state which is saved to localStorage and if it's true, show the hidden panel automatically.

Please see my code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var panelOpen = localStorage.getItem("panelOpen");

    if (panelOpen == "true") {
        $("#slidermenu-bar").slideReveal("show");
    }
});

$(function () {
    $("#slidermenu-bar").slideReveal({
        push: false,
        position: "left",
        trigger: $(".handle"),
        shown: function (obj) {
            localStorage.setItem("panelOpen", true);
            obj.find(".handle").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Open');

        },
        hidden: function (obj) {
            localStorage.setItem("panelOpen", false);
            obj.find(".handle").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Close');
        }
    });
});
```

If anyone can assist, it would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is real close to be working.

**First**, from what I know, `$(document).ready(function () {` and `$(function () {` both are "on ready" blocks.
If there is a difference between them, it is pretty subtile because I never noticed!

So you can place all your script in the same "ready" block.
Now just instantiate `slideReveal` on `$("#slidermenu-bar")` **before** the check in local storage.

;)

Comment: Ok, I have tried that. I now have `if (logoutPanelOpen == "true") {var slider = $("#slidermenu-bar").slideReveal({push: false,position: "left"});slider.slideReveal("show");}` I can see it briefly pop out, before hiding again. If I use `if (logoutPanelOpen == "true") {var slider = $("#slidermenu-bar").slideReveal();slider.slideReveal("show");}` the screen slides to the right but the handle and hidden panel stay where they are until the handle is clicked and out slides the panel, this is very frustrating LOL

Comment: You hit on the problem with `First, from what I know, $(document).ready(function () { and $(function () { both are "on ready" blocks.` so basically the document ready fired first, which opened it and then function block outside the document ready, closed it again. Thank you, this now works.

Comment: I rolled back to remove the setTimeout story... ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is much appreciated :-)

Comment: Thanks, your "must INSTANTIATE" comment helped me

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Louys Patrice Bessette, that identified the issue related to ready blocks, please see the working code below:

```
var panelOpen = localStorage.getItem("panelOpen");

var slider = $("#slidermenu-bar").slideReveal({
    push: false,
    position: "left",
    trigger: $(".handle"),
    shown: function (obj) {
        localStorage.setItem("panelOpen", true);
        obj.find(".handle").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> Open');

    },
    hidden: function (obj) {
        localStorage.setItem("panelOpen", false);
        obj.find(".handle").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> Close');
    }
});

if (panelOpen == "true") {
    slider.slideReveal("show");
} else {
    slider.slideReveal("hide");
}
```